# How do you save a list as a file from Python?

Tags: python, save

I created a simple program that lets you input a set of numbers, then creates a randomly generated list of pairs from the data that was given by the person.
How can I save the data (as a Windows file) once it finishes?
This is my code:

```
import random as ran
import easygui as eg
nList=vList=eg.multenterbox(msg="Enter the names of the people:"
                , title="Random Pair Generator"
                , fields=('Name:', 'Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:','Name:',)
                , values=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20']
                )

index=0
x=''
y=''
pList=[]
pair=''

while not(index==len(nList)):
   x=nList[index]
   y=ran.choice(vList)
   pair=x+'; '+y
   pList.insert(index, pair)
   vList.remove(y)
   index= index+1

    eg.textbox(msg="These are the pairs generated."
                , title= "Random Pair Generator"
                , text= str(pList)
                , codebox=0
                )
```

I just want to save pList as a file, anywhere on my computer (preferably somewhere I can specify).
Also, this loop creates an issue. It doesn't raise an error with syntax or anything, but the output is not what I want it to be.

What it does is it uses each value from nList, then picks a random value from vList, and then puts those as one object into pList. However, the problem arises that when I have it delete the output of "y" from vList, it also removes it from nList.

Example: If nList contains 5 objects: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and vList has the same objects [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. It would select a random number from vList for every value in nList.
However, once a variable from vList is chosen, it is removed from the list. The problem is that say pList starts as [1; 2] where 1; 2 is one object, the next object would start at 3. It would skip over 2 because 2 was already used as a 'y' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save the list of pairs in the same format as it was displayed in your `eg.textbox`, add something like this to end of your program:

```
filename = eg.filesavebox(msg=None
                        , title='Save Pair List'
                        , default="pairs.txt"
                        , filetypes=['*.txt']
                        )

with open(filename, 'wt') as output:
    output.write(str(pList)+'\n')
```

You could write each pair of the list on a separate line of the output file like this:

```
with open(filename, 'wt') as output:
    for pair in pList:
        output.write(pair+'\n')
```

Using the `with` statement means the file will be closed for you automatically after the block of code it controls is finished.

Comment: Thanks! This worked to save it... But any way I could fix my second issue? With 20 values in nList, it only generates 10 pairs, because once a value from vList (which is the same as nList originally) is used, it somehow gets taken off BOTH nList and vList, whereas I want it to only be taken off of vList.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't (and still don't) quite understand what you were trying to achieve with respect to in the second part of your question. A general thought though, you might be able to avoid the issue of removing elements from the list(s) by using the `random.shuffle()` function.

Comment: Also regarding the second issue: The problem you're having with changes to `vlist` also changing `nlist` could be avoided by making one an independent _copy_ of the other by doing this `nList=vList[:]` on a separate line. The way you have it now, they're both just different names for the same list which is why changes affect both.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Didn't know you had to do that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it's customary to also up-vote the answer you accept if you like it.

Comment: I was going to do that but was unable to because of my reputation... Now I can so I will

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Thanks, and good luck with your program. BTW, it's usually best to just ask one question at a time if possible on S.O.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear for me if you'd like to write your `pList` as plain text, or as a list you can easily reopen later...

The first case is easy:

```
f = open("path/your_filename.txt", 'w') # opening file object for writing (creates one if not found)
f.write(str(pList))                     # writing list as a string into your file
f.close()                               # closing file object
```

You cannot write non-string Python objects directly into file. If you would like to retain you object type too (so you can load it later on), one of the easiest way is to use `pickle`:

```
import pickle

f = open("/path/your_filename.pkl", 'w')
pickle.dump(f, pList)
f.close()
```

And load it as:

```
import pickle

f = open("/path/your_filename.pkl", 'r') # opening file object for reading
pList = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Hope this helps.